# How to get normal/custom error response for an exception from an Action returning Stream in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have been venturing in the ServiceStack's [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling) regarding an issue with throwing *Exceptions* from an Action that returns a *Stream*.

The issue is that while all the other Actions in my service return beautiful errors like:

```
{
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "ArgumentException",
    "Message": "Unable to load data",
    "StackTrace": "[GetData: 7/11/2016 1:02:11 PM]:\n[REQUEST: {Token:asdf,Id:1}]\nServiceStack.HttpError: Unable to load codes from token ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to load codes from token.............(abridged)
  }
}
```

There is an Action with the return type as Stream from which, regardless of the type of exception returned, the http client receives the following response:

With the handler (as per the SS documentation):

```
Error: ArgumentNullException: As result 'ErrorResponse' is not a supported responseType, a defaultAction must be supplied
Parameter name: defaultAction
```

And without any handlers:

```
'no content'
```

400

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sample Code-->

Here is an example of the Action:

```
[AddHeader(ContentType = "application/pdf")]
public Stream Get(GetPdfRequest request)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("FAKE EXCEPTION");
}
```

and in the APPHOST's Configure() method:

```
this.UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) =>
            {
                var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
                logger.Error("Unhandled error in API during request binding.", ex);

                res.Write("Error: {0}: {1}".Fmt(ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
                res.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
            });

this.ServiceExceptionHandlers.Add((httpReq, request, exception) =>
            {
                var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
                logger.Error("Unhandled error in API.", exception);

                //call default SS exception handler
                return DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, exception);
            });
```

Here is a screenshot of what I see on the Swagger Rest client when the above Action is called.

[image: Exception on Swagger]

Comment: Can you provide sample code we can use to repro this issue?

Comment: Hi @mythz: Added the sample Action and also a part of (related) code in the AppHost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is due to being unable to serialize the `ErrorResponse` DTO into the unregistered "application/pdf" ContentType.

I've just added a fallback to use the `Config.DefaultContentType` for serializing errors in unregistered Content Types [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/87a8b1e16e4848e16d05a212bdd75290910b61e4), available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

A workaround for prior versions of ServiceStack is instead of using the `[AddHeader]` Request Filter Attribute, to instead set the Content-Type in the Service implementation just before you serialize, so any Exceptions are thrown before Response ContentType is set, e.g:

```
public class ErrorStream {}
public class ErrorStreamService : Service
{
    public Stream Any(ErrorStream request)
    {
        if (!IsValid(request))
            throw new NotImplementedException("Exception in Stream Response");

       base.Request.ResponseContentType = "application/pdf";

       return PdfAsStream(request);
    }
}
```

Which throws a Typed Exception when using a Service Client:

```
try
{
    var response = client.Get<Stream>(new ErrorStream());
    Assert.Fail();
}
catch (WebServiceException ex)
{
    Assert.That(ex.IsAny400());
    Assert.That(!ex.IsAny500());
    Assert.That(ex.ErrorCode, Is.EqualTo("NotImplementedException"));
    Assert.That(ex.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo((int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed));
}
```

Also `UncaughtExceptionHandlers` is only for handling Exceptions thrown outside of a Service, exceptions that occur within a Service are instead handled by `ServiceExceptionHandlers` instead, but be careful when modifying the default Exception handling behavior as you can invalidate the typed Exception handling on the client.

Comment: There's ServiceExceptionHandlers too in the AppHost. Sorry I skipped that before. Now I notice that both the Unhandled and ServiceException Handlers are getting invoked on the exception.

Comment: @Vaibhav I've updated my answer with a fallback to handle this case of serializing errors when using an unregistered callback that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) as well as a work around to set the Response Content Type in the Service implementation for existing releases of ServiceStack.

Comment: I think your update worked. That 'content header' was the problem. Thanks for the help!